# Xero API - How to retrieve Payments which are awaiting approval?

Tags: xero-api

The API allows me to search for Payments endpoint below with Status="AUTHORISED" but how can I search for payments which are awaiting approval?

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments
```

Comment: Does `Status!="AUTHORISED"` not do it? According to the doc, there's only AUTHORISED and DELETED, which suggests that any other would have no status. What is the actual status of your payments if you retrieve one in the API explorer and have a look? (I can't check, mine are all sent as "authorised")

Comment: Also, check the doc on using the "where" parameter, there's something about checking against null to prevent exceptions if some values are missing, and I'm not sure if that would apply here. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/requests-and-responses